# Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[0,1]$ such that $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx =0$ for all $a$, $b$ belonging to [0,1]. Then what can we say about $f$?

Tags: integration, continuity

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[0,1]$ such that $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx =0$ for all $a$, $b$ belonging to $[0,1]$.

Then what can we say about $f$?

I can show that if $f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x$ belonging to $[0,1]$ then $f$ must be identically zero to satisfy the stated condition. But I how can I proceed here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Suppose $f(a) \neq 0$ for some $a \in [0,1]$. Since $f$ is continuous, show there is an interval $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$ on which $f<0$ or $f>0$. Then choose convenient values of $a$ and $b$ for which $\int_a^b f(x) \ dx$ cannot be $0$.

Answer (score 0):

We can say that $f\equiv 0$.

Assume otherwise, say $f(x_0)=y_0\ne 0$ for some $y_0\in [0,1]$. If $y_0>0$, then $f(x)>\frac12 y_0$ in a neighbourhood of $x_0$. Hence in a sufficiently small interval $[a,b]$ around $x_0$, we have $\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx\ge (b-a)\frac{y_0}2>0$, contradiction. The same argument works for $y_0<0$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a<c<b$ and $f(c)\ne0$. For small $\epsilon$,
$$\int_{c-\epsilon}^{c+\epsilon}f(x)\,dx$$
is about $2\epsilon f(c)$, but it's also zero.

Comment: Thank you @Lord Shark the Unknown

Answer (score 0):

If there is just one point where $f$ is not $0$, then let $a,b$ be very close to that one point. If they're close enough, then $f$ will stay on the same side of the $x$-axis throughout the interval $[a,b]$ (since $f$ is continuous), so the integral over that interval will not be $0$.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is a quickie. Take any $t \in [0,1]$ such that $f(t)>0$. Using the continuity, pick $\epsilon=\frac{f(t)}{2}$ and corresponding $\delta>0$ such that
$$
|t-x|<\delta \implies |f(t)-f(x)|<\epsilon,
$$
hence for every $x \in (t-\delta,t+\delta)$, $f(x)>\frac{f(t)}{2}$. Now, consider the interval
$$
I=(\max\{0,t-\delta\},\min\{1,t+\delta\})
$$
in order to make sure we are in the interval $[0,1]$. Then,
$$
\int_{I}f(x)dx > \ell(I)\frac{f(t)}{2}>0
$$
where $\ell(I)$ is the length of the interval $I$.