# If the integral of this continuous function is zero, is it the zero function?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$, and suppose that $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function such that for each $t\in [a,b]$, $\int_{a}^tf(s)\,ds=0$. Is it true that $f$ is identically zero on $[a,b]$?

In case of  $f\geq0$ on $[a,b]$, then clearly the above condition would imply $f=0$ on $[a,b]$; but note that here $f$ can take negative values, as well as, positive values. However, we assume that the above integral is zero for each $t\geq a$, so intuitively I think that the function $f$ should be identically zero on $[a,b]$.

Can anybody give a hint? Thanks in advence.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2267397/42969

Comment: Hint: What is the derivative  of $\int_a^t f(s)ds$ with respect to $t$?

Comment: The negation of the statement that $f$ is identically zero is that there is at least one point where $f$ is not $0.$ Then the problem is to show that if $f$ is nonzero at one point AND $f$ is continuous there, than $f$ is nonzero and has the same sign everywhere in some interval about that one point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We require that:
$$\int_0^t f(s) ds = 0$$
Take derivative of both sides:
$$f(t)=0$$
So I think yes, $f(t)$ should be zero.

---

*I am not a mathematican and this is my first answer to a question which isn't mine :) So: no guarantees that this is correct.*